# How to update XML in ntext column?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I have an xml of this structure in an ntext column

```
<car>
<model>Accord</model>
<engine></engine>
<description><p>As new</p></description>
<notes><p>English</p></notes>
</car>
```

I would like to update `<description>` column, lets say, to have `<p>As <b>new</b><p>`.

I have tried using intermediary tables but when I say

```
insert into @Temp (xdoc) 
select CAST(xml as xml) from MyTable
WHERE Id = @Id
```

xdoc in @Temp table contains escaped html chars

```
<description>&lt;p&gt;As new&lt;/p&gt;</description>
```

I can't do `for xml explicit` with `insert` or assignment statements.

Should I go with `REPLACE` to replace escaped chars with proper chars, or is there a better way?

Comment: Can you change the ntext column to be an xml column?  That should be your long term goal.

Comment: I know it should be, but I cant change it now  :(

Comment: I have currenlty a very similar question, my current approach is to use a temporary table with column type 'xml' - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64140808/how-to-use-modify-method-on-a-ntext-column-without-changin-column-type-to-x